# Can blood disinfect a house from plague according to Leviticus?

Tags: leviticus

We know blood is a good media of germs, bacteria, as well as toxin. But Leviticus, Ch. No.14, Verse No.49 to 53 - tells a way for disinfecting a house from plague of leprosy.

It states ‘Take two birds, kill one bird, take wood, scale it - and the other living bird, dip it in water and under running water - later on sprinkle the house 7 times with it. 
Does it work and how?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: per above comment, see here: [Is Leviticus 14 describing a cure for leprosy?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/is-leviticus-14-describing-a-cure-for-leprosy?rq=1)

[Leviticus 14:1-9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2014:1-9&version=AMP)

> 14 And the Lord said to Moses,
>
> 2 This shall be the law of the leper on the day when he is to be
>   pronounced clean: he shall be brought to the priest [at a meeting
>   place outside the camp];
>
> 3 The priest shall go out of the camp [to meet him]; and [he] shall
>   examine him, and if the disease is healed in the leper,
>
> 4 Then the priest shall command to take for him who is to be cleansed
>   two living clean birds and cedar wood and scarlet [material] and
>   hyssop.
>
> 5 And the priest shall command to kill one of the birds in an earthen
>   vessel over fresh, running water.
>
> 6 As for the living bird, he shall take it, the cedar wood, and the
>   scarlet [material], and the hyssop, and shall dip them and the living
>   bird in the blood of the bird killed over the running water;
>
> 7 And he shall sprinkle [the blood] on him who is to be cleansed from
>   the leprosy seven times and shall pronounce him clean, and shall let
>   go the living bird into the open field.

This very likely has nothing to do with literal sanitation, but like many things of the law, its a reflection of heavenly things, heavenly benefits, and quite often the things involved are **symbolisms** * although the people of their day took it literal.

Looking at verse 2-3 it appears this is *a ritual  upon being pronounced* clean - *not on the cleansing itself*.

**The law is a reflection of heavenly things:**

[Hebrews 8:5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%208:5&version=AMP)

> 5 [But these offer] service [merely] as a pattern and as a
>   foreshadowing of [what has its true existence and reality in] the
>   heavenly sanctuary. For when Moses was about to erect the tabernacle,
>   he was warned by God, saying, See to it that you make it all [exactly]
>   according to the copy (the model) which was shown to you on the
>   mountain.